# Project Server 2013 - "An unknown error has occured"

Tags: project-server

Whenever I navigate to Project Center in Project Server 2013 the credentials window pops-up continuously even after entering correct admin account and after several clicks on Ok button in credential window it says,

> "An unknown error has occurred"

This is happening at every links even at Resources, Tasks, Reports,etc. Is this Project Server 2013 stable or still has bugs in it ?

I recently installed March 2013 hotfix for Project Server but still no luck. In ULS or Event Viewer I didn't got any relevant exceptions.

I am even unable to connect to Project Server from Project Professional.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case Anonymous authentication was disabled for the Project Server web application on IIS level. It must be enabled for  SharePoint web applications with claims authentication configured.

Answer (score 0):

Open Event Viewer.
In Event Viewer, I have noticed that there is exception message related to the SharePoint portal
Now, open SharePoint Management Shell as a farm account.
List all databases information that has not been synchronized with the user profile service by typing the following cmdlet one by one.
stsadm -o sync -listolddatabases n
stsadm -o sync -deleteolddatabases n
The ‘–listolddatabases‘ command lists
the content databases that have not been synchronized since ‘n’ days.
The ‘deleteolddatabases‘ command performs
the same operation as the listolddatabases parameter, except it deletes old records corresponding to these databases. It does not delete the databases themselves. Once the synchronization references are deleted and a new profile synchronization occurs, new references will be stored in the database.
Based on the Error log that related to  UserMemberShips. thence, the issue might be related to Project Resources.
Go back to the last published projects > open its schedule.
From project Professional > File > Save & Send > Save As.
Click Map Resources then Continue to step 2 until finish the import project wizard.

Hope You Find This Useful,
Peter

Answer (score -1):

pls review this blog hope it solve your issue 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brismith/archive/2010/07/02/project-server-2010-an-unknown-error-has-occurred-in-project-center-resource-center-or-tasks.aspx

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Comment: Please read the question first then post your answer, the answer is for 2010, his question is for 2013 you know there are allot of changes.